# How to use PactDslJsonBody for an object within an object

Tags: java, json, object, pact, contract

Trying to implement Contract Testing using Pact.
I'm starting off with Consumer side right now. It is event-driven messages so I am using MessagePactBuilder

I will give an example of what I have and what I'm trying to achieve.

What I currently have:

```
@Pact
public MessagePact validMessage(MessagePactBuilder builder){
 PactDslJsonBody body = new PactDslJsonBody();

 body.object("student")
     .stringType("studentFirstName")
     .stringType("studentLastName")
     .stringType("studentAddress") // I understand this won't work. 

 Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
 metadata.put("contentType", "application/json");

 return builder
        .given("validMessage")
        .expectsToReceive()
        .withMetadata(metadata)
        .withContent(body)
        .toPact();
}
```

The issue I have is the student class is composed of

```
String studentFirstName
String studentLastName
Address studentAddress
```

So you can see that it is also taking in an Address object.
The Address object consists of all strings

```
String addressLine
String city
String state
String zip
```

Any ideas on how I can create the PactDslJsonBody this way? Or if I need to implement it another way? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some examples at https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer#examples

In your case, using the `PactDslJsonBody`, it would look like the following:

```java
body
  .object("student")
    .stringType("studentFirstName")
    .stringType("studentLastName") 
    .object("studentAddress") 
      .stringType("adressLine")
      .stringType("city")
      // Others...
    .closeObject()
  .closeObject()
```

*(False indentation to match the JSON structure)*

This can become very verbose and hard to read because of missing indentation. That's why there's an alternative syntax using `LambdaDsl`:

```java
newJsonBody((o) -> {
    o.object("student", (s) -> {
      s.stringType("studentFirstName");
      s.object("studentAddress", (a) -> {
        a.stringType("adressLine");
        // Others...
      });
      // Others...
    });
})
.build();
```

This syntax naturally looks' like the JSON structure even though it's still quite verbose.

If you want less verbose syntax, only alternative is to use Kotlin or Scala.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I were to change Address studentAddress into <List> studentAddress. How would I create the Dsl in that scenario?

Comment: There's a similar method called `array` I believe. Your IDE should help finding available methods.